# which marker is tapped in Google Maps SDK ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have many markers in `GMSMapView`. I want to know which marker is tapped.
I know that there is `- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker` delegate. But my problem is when i tap any marker, i will show different information for every marker in `infoWindow`. So, i must know which marker is tapped.How can i do this?

Comment: Check out something easier for doing your job. As I had given in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the marker, set its `userData` property to an instance of your own class which stores data about the marker.

Then in `didTapMarker`, you can get out the `userData` property, cast it to your own type, and then extract the details you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the **accessibilityLabel** property of marker during its creation from your data.

For example you are creating the markers from an array of objects then set the **marker.accessibilityLabel** of each marker as its position in your array so when user is going to tap on any marker, just find its accessibilityLabel and so find the data from array at this position.

Comment: amazing, just amazing.